# iterating over dynamically augmented iterator

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am iterating over lines of a file, but if a line matches a certain pattern, I first need to recursively iterate over another file. I'm using `itertools.chain` to extend the iterator. The problem is (probably) that the for loop in the `__iter__` method makes a copy of the initial iterator so I'm not iterating over the updated one.

```
import itertools
class LineGenerator():
    instance = None
    class __linegenerator():
        def __init__(self):
            self.generator = []; self.linecount = 0
        def inputfile(self,filename):
            print(f"add input file: {filename}")
            self.generator = itertools.chain( open(filename),self.generator )
        def __iter__(self):
            for l in self.generator:
                l = l.strip("\n")
                self.linecount += 1
                yield l
    def __new__(cls):
        if not LineGenerator.instance:
            LineGenerator.instance = LineGenerator.__linegenerator()
        return LineGenerator.instance
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return self.instance.__getattr__(attr)

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open("lines1","w") as lines1:
        lines1.write("a\n")
        lines1.write("b\n")
        lines1.write("c\n")
    with open("lines2","w") as lines2:
        lines2.write("aa\n")
        lines2.write("bb\n")
        lines2.write("cc\n")
    LineGenerator().inputfile("lines1")
    for l in LineGenerator():
        print(f"{l}")
        if l=="b":
            LineGenerator().inputfile("lines2")
```

(I hope you can forgive my use of a singleton pattern)

Output:

```
add input file: lines1
a
b
add input file: lines2
c
```

Desired output:

```
add input file: lines1
a
b
add input file: lines2
aa
bb
cc
c
```

Question: how can this design be fixed? I would like to keep the main program as it stands.

Comment: For loops do not copy iterators.

Comment: Ad an aside, why this convoluted nested class design? What is its purpose?

Comment: So, chain doesn't extend the iterator. It creates a new one, which you assign to `self.generator`. That won't affect whatever is happening in the for loop, since the iterator is resolved once in the `for` clause

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html regarding the singleton pattern.

Comment: There's no question. And no clear description of the task you want to solve.

Comment: @KellyBundy Fair point. Edited: "how can I fix it so that this API gives the desired behavior".

Comment: @chepner Yes, I know, but in this application there is really global data, so either I can make a global variable, or use this pattern. There will *never* be two independent line generators in my application. LaTeX -> html translator, in case you're wondering. For each program run there is exactly one file being translated, so this is truly global data.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Did you read the link I posted, particularly [this section](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html#h_but_i_thought_globals_were_bad)?  "But I thought globals were bad?
They are bad, but your Singleton was also a global: there was only one for the whole process, and it could be changed from anywhere. It wasn’t literally a Python global variable, but it had all the same bad qualities, just hidden behind some tricky meta-programming. If you’re going to have a global, be up-front about it."

Comment: @chepner My global is hidden, but it's in an object which means that nice methods are defined on it. But this is beside the point. If you can save my API with a global, feel free to post your solution. And then I will encapsulate it out of your offended sight.

Comment: And your object will *still* have the same methods if you get rid of the singleton cruft.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##dYwxCsMwDEV3n0JospdCk6UUPHfJJRqQiUDIRvFSQs/uOu6ct3x4PH751C3r/CjWmrDSDhGWvi9SsnfN5oMb/sa6k9XEQh6HuWNwKRsIsMIwTwedYqzVJzzk24vTcAKJEVf8BycXnxOG1n4) would be more normal and could be implemented much more easily. Would that suffice? I think @chepner simply has, like me, no interest in making your rather complicated singleton thingy work, but we could rather easily implement such a more normal way.

Comment: @KellyBundy How did you implement the `insertfile` method? That's the crux.

Comment: I didn't. I might, if you agree that this changed user-code, i.e., the changed API, is acceptable.

Comment: @KellyBundy Sure. Whether it's a singleton, a globally known object, a global variable, as long it is solves the problem that I want to extend an iteratable something that is permanent, that is, accessible through one global name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way that achieves the result (changed a bit, as discussed in the comments). It keeps iterators on a stack and always gives the next line of the top iterator:

```
class LineIterator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.iterator_stack = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def insertfile(self, filename):
        print(f"add input file: {filename}")
        def gen():
            with open(filename) as f:
                yield from f
        self.iterator_stack.append(gen())

    def __next__(self):
        stack = self.iterator_stack
        while stack:
            try:
                return next(stack[-1]).strip("\n")
            except StopIteration:
                stack.pop()
        raise StopIteration


if __name__=="__main__":
    with open("lines1","w") as lines1:
        lines1.write("a\n")
        lines1.write("b\n")
        lines1.write("c\n")
    with open("lines2","w") as lines2:
        lines2.write("aa\n")
        lines2.write("bb\n")
        lines2.write("cc\n")
    lines = LineIterator()
    lines.insertfile("lines1")
    for l in lines:
        print(f"{l}")
        if l=="b":
            lines.insertfile("lines2")
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPLbsMgELz7KxAnLKWW4l6qSPmASr31mEaI2NCgEkBA5ERRv93lkdg4TrMnw8zu7A5rfXZ7JV/ftOn7RhBrwQeX9N1RQ5wyq6IAPlrKAMZccocxslSwchXvQ4Rjxa98bB1pfsAabLaTTA/PMw11RyNjgZHMpaXGMS5opC9A@JTkQLNEbbh0iEHStp6vjy6SVuBy4/7CciCHot9Uoiw/RMfdHijtgUEAEAvYlBXizKloATPqANizqSuifbkWRbEyH1/S0yPjrlY9KDVwur1vLjGnjTlznnd6NTTIoZizeVluy8o6wzWCXzJzJQQ9NVQ78OmUTu/NlZwXTbNppdGYbQi3dJpYFAWPs3onMV6vIcYHwiXGMJUc/YbCL5hdwgXsYPQ8nUfldK46401BkEz6nmK7J1gzYPfS9Z10fSddD9IPtAdwt3sCNqN6BPwz578VyqAq2/ibNQlmygDhFzzx5ut/Efmee/eFt30Hp0/4j0YNy77/Aw)):

```
add input file: lines1
a
b
add input file: lines2
aa
bb
cc
c
```